# Prime subfield when $ch(F) = 0$; shouldn't it be prime subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose $ch(F)=0$ and let $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to F$ with $\phi:n \mapsto n \cdot 1_F$. Since the characteristic is $0$, we have $\ker \phi = \{0 \}$. By the First Isomorphism Theorem, we have $\mathbb{Z} / \{ 0\}\cong \text{Im}(\phi)$. But the ring on the right is just $\mathbb{Z}$, and the ring on the left is the prime "subfield" of $F$. Could someone point out the problem please?

Answer (score 2):

Your $\phi$ is the morphism of the initial object in the category of unital rings to the ring $F$. If the codomain is a field of prime characteristic, then the image of the morphism is not just a subring, but a subfield. This is due to the fact that the prime non-zero ideals of $\Bbb Z$ are also maximal. If not, then it's just a subring.

Comment: Sorry I'm having trouble understanding your answer. In $\mathbb{Z} / \{ 0\}\cong \text{Im}(\phi)$, is the ring on the left not $\mathbb{Z}$, or is the ring on the right not the prime subfield?

Comment: $\operatorname{im}\phi$ is not a subfield.

Comment: Maybe my definition of prime subfield is wrong; as I understand it, the prime subfield of $F$ is the set of all finite sums of $1$, or $\{ n \cdot 1_F| n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. I think that $\text {Im}(\phi) = \{ n \cdot 1_F| n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$. So why am I getting that this object is not a field, when it should be?

Comment: Your definition of prime subfield is not correct. The prime subfield of a field is its smallest subfield, which contains not only all the integer multiples of $1_F$, but in the case of a field of characteristic 0, all its rational multiples as well.

Comment: But in Dummit & Foote, (as you can also see on the wolfram alpha website here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSubfield.html) it says that the prime subfield of a field is the field generated by $1_F$. Why isn't this the same as $\{ n \cdot 1_F| n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$?

Comment: @Ovi note that it says *field* generated by $1_F$, so it's the set of sums and products *and quotients* that you obtain by starting with $1_F$.

Comment: @jgon OH thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The image of $\varphi$ is *not* the prime subfield of $F$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$. The problem is that $\phi$ is a morphism of *rings*, and not a morphism of *fields*. Therefore, you could think of $\operatorname{im}(\varphi)$ as being a sort of "prime *subring*" associated to $F$, but it is not a field. In general, for any field of characteristic 0, there is a unique field homomorphism $\psi:\mathbb{Q} \to F$ whose image is the prime subfield associated to $F$, and which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$.